# Obtain certain value from an expression

Tags: linear-algebra

I apologize in advance if my question is trivial but I really cannot decide if my method is logically correct or not. Suppose I have this expression:

$$(x \times y)+i$$

Where $x$, $y$ and $i$ are integers, $i$ is always from a fixed range. My goal is to obtain $i$, is it true to say: $((x \times y)+i)/(x \times y)$ as $(x \times y)$ here cancel each other?

Thank you

Comment: What is the context? Are $x$ and $y$ real numbers? Does "$*$" denote multiplication of real numbers?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thank you. Just updated my post.

Comment: $\dfrac{xy+i}{xy}=1+\dfrac{i}{xy}$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Oh right thanks. So I can solve for $i$

Comment: Perhaps the identity  $$(xy + i) - xy = i $$ would help?

Comment: If you know what $xy+i$ equals, then you can solve for $i$, but not by dividing by $xy$.